# How to reference MODI component to web hosting?

Tags: c#, .net, modi

I built a web application using MODI component to do OCR. In my localhost, I installed Microsoft Office and it worked fine. But when I uploaded my project to web hosting, it showed error message:

**Could not load type 'MODI.IDocument' from assembly 'Thumbnailer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The type is marked as eligible for type equivalence, but the containing assembly is not loaded as fully trusted.**

I've tried to put MDIVWCTL.dll to 'bin' folder, but it didn't work. Is there any way to reference MODI without installing Microsoft Office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. Go to MODI component's properties in your project references and change 'Copy Local' to true.