# Not able to create Docker Image

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

`I have added COM reference in my project i.e(MODI) for converting image to text .
while creating docker build for creating image in terminal i am getting below error.

/app/Services/ConvertPdftoWord.cs(18,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MODI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/ModiOcr.csproj]

Even while adding COM reference it automatically .csproj file added below line

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="MODI" Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' != 'Core'">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>12</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>a5ededf4-2bbc-45f3-822b-e60c278a1a79</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Dockerfile i have attached and i am new to Docker Please help on this.[image]
`

how to resolve this issue do i need to include COM referene into Dockerfile?

Comment: It is probably not possible to compile this in a Linux container, but I am not 100% sure. Maybe this question is relatable for your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17720923/7081176

Comment: i am trying to compile into windows machinee only.let me try above solution

Comment: Yes, but you compile/build it using Docker, this means that it is probably compiling in a linux environment anyways.

Comment: The compiler isn't even attempting to use the COM component because you've dynamically excluded it out of the project file with `Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' != 'Core'"`. Was that intentional? If so, you'd also need to update the code to also have similar conditions to not expect that namespace to exist when compiling for .NET Core.

Comment: Yes,Intentionally i did because if i not add i am getting below error =>/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.402/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2927,5): error MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild. See https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803 for further details. [/app/ModiOcr.csproj]

Comment: Hi @MattThalman  Thalman I have created dotnet core webapi project and using interop.MODI.dll this component is 32 bit component while running locally getting error but if i ran with Platform Target as X86 i am not getting any error(Using this dll i am convertting image to text) .when i try to create image in Docker Desktop i am getting The type or namespace name 'MODI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/ModiOcr.csproj] erro ,so do i need to include MODI.dll into DOckerfile ?Thanks in Advance